# How to select the part of a column between _ and a

Tags: postgresql

i have a column **href**  which contiens a liste of links

| href |
| --- |
| 100712107%23C3.3_.pdf |
| 100712107~%23C3.2_C00.zip |
| 100740104_C2.3.xls |
| testme_aze_--b00.xls |

My ouput would be

| href | name | rev |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100712107%23C3.3_.pdf | 100712107%23C3.3 |  |
| 100712107~%23C3.2_C00.zip | 100712107~%23C3.2 | C00 |
| 100740104_C2.3.xls | 100740104 | C2.3 |
| testme_aze_--b00.xls | testme_aze | --b00 |

I have tried to use ** reverse(split_part(reverse(href),'.',1))**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract a substring pattern in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381174/how-to-extract-a-substring-pattern-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex together with `substring()` to extract the parts you want:

```
select href, 
       substring(href from '(.*)_') as name,
       substring(href from '.*_(.*)\.') as rev
from the_table
```

returns:

```
href                      | name              | rev  
--------------------------+-------------------+------
100712107%23C3.3_.pdf     | 100712107%23C3.3  |      
100712107~%23C3.2_C00.zip | 100712107~%23C3.2 | C00  
100740104_C2.3.xls        | 100740104         | C2.3 
testme_aze_--b00.xls      | testme_aze        | --b00
```

`substring()` will return the first group from the regex. The firs regex matches all characters until the last `_`.

The second expression matches everything after the last `_` up until the last `.`

Answer (score -1):

#### You want add a column to the table ?

```sql
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN HREF VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```